# MATLAB 16uc1 or 32fc1 Conversion

Tags: ros, matlab, ros-kinetic, depth-image, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some image processing code in MATLAB and am attempting to use it with ROS. I read in a PointCloud2 object and execute `readRGB(ptcloud)` and `readXYZ(ptcloud)` where I get two MATLAB images each of size 480x640x3.

**Q1: I assume that a depth image of size NxMx3 gives X, Y, and Z distances as the three channels. Is this correct??**

I then execute my processing and need to send a depth image back encoded in either 16uc1 or 32fc1. I have not found a built-in MATLAB function for this. I can write a conversion script myself but I am unfamiliar with these formats.

**Q2: What is the general algorithm to convert my NxMx3 matrix into either format?**

My depth camera node publishes a depth image in the 16uc1 format. When I subscribe to that in MATLAB and execute `readImage(ros_image)` I get an image of size 480x640x1 in MATLAB but when I execute `rostopic echo /ros_depth_image_topic` I see the data is given as "data: array: type uint8, length: 614400".

**Q3: I notice this is 480*640*2 so why does MATLAB only read in a 480x640x1 image? How do the 614400 data points translate to only 307200 data points in MATLAB?**

Thank you for any assistance offered!

================================================================================

Update 1:
I went back over [REP-118 -- Depth Images](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0118.html) and understand the the distance in a depth image is the distance from the camera's z-axis. Therefore why would MATLAB's `readXYZ(ptcloud)` function give me a 3 channel image when a depth image is only 1 channel?
Also: the 16UC1 states [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/readimage.html#buqwfob) that it supports int16 but I believe ROS wants uint16. When I get 2x the data represented as UInt8 does that just mean there are two 8-bit words basically being concatenated into one 16-bit data point? In other words, is each pixel represented as two UInt8 data points in the 16UC1?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292031/matlab-16uc1-or-32fc1-conversion/) by [cmfuhrman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33793/cmfuhrman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hopefully I can shed some light on this for you.

**Q1:** Reading a PointCloud2 using readXYZ(ptCloud) is not producing a depth image it's producing a structured point cloud, they are different data structures. Each pixel is either null (zero usually) or a Cartesian point in the sensors optical frame. By convention this has Z pointing into the view, X pointing right and Y pointing down.

**Q2:** You're trying to convert a structured point cloud into a depth image, this is easy you just throw away the X and Y data. The Z values are the depth, if you know the lens model and calibration parameters of the depth camera then you can always re-create those X and Y values later. To convert to unsigned 16 bit integers use the [uint16() function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html) or to convert to 32 bit floating points use the [single() function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html).

**Q3:** The array size in the data array is simply the number of bytes of data stored, each pixel of your depth image requires two bytes. So there are 480 x 640 x 2 bytes in the message.

**Re Update:** As said readXYZ() does not give you a depth image. Your last point is correct each pixel is two Uint8's otherwise known as bytes.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cmfuhrman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33793/cmfuhrman/) on 2018-05-23**:
Thank you! I could not find any information about readXYZ and could only guess as to the meaning of the channels.